# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException

Tags: spring, hibernate, database-connection, sessionfactory

I have a spring project where for that i am using mysql as the database.I have configured the Tomcat JDBC connection pool in servelet configuration file and the connection is working fine in my local machine.But recently I have recreated our remote server and there after am getting below error when i am trying to access database.

```
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

So what will be the reason for this error.The same project have no issues earlier and the issue comes after recreating the server.I can access the remote server mysql database from phpmyadmin using the same username and password.Also no problem when we run the project within local machine and local mysql database.
Below is my spring servlet configuration file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
    <!-- @author Nagesh.Chauhan(neel4soft@gmail.com) -->
        <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.myproject" >
    <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.example.myproject.controller.MyController"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>    
         <!--  in above  <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />    -->

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">  

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
     <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000000" />
    </bean>  

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SampleDb"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="mypassword"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.example.myproject</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
  <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

This is how i am using the session in my service class :

```
    @Repository
@Transactional
public class MyMainService implements MainDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private org.hibernate.Session getCurrentSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    // just a sample
    @Override
    public void setUser(String idStr, Integer age) {
        UserSample newUserSam = new UserSample();
        try{
            newUserSam.setAge(age);
            newUserSam.setId(idStr);
            getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(newUserSam);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my pom.xml file :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
    <!-- Spring Security OAuth2 -->
    <spring-security-oauth2-version>2.0.8.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
<!-- Spring Security OAuth2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20070829</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>  

    <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto -->
<!--    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>        -->
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java EE -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Others -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
        <version>0.9</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.5</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fifesoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>autocomplete</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
    <artifactId>swingx-autocomplete</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.glazedlists</groupId>
        <artifactId>glazedlists_java15</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you post the code in which you have initialized the sessionfactory?

Comment: @Akshay I have eddited the code with a sample sessionfactory usage.

Comment: What is your hibernate version??Also have you updated your Tomcat version?

Comment: <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>

Comment: @Akshay On recreation of server tomcat version also updated.

Comment: I think that may be the reason.During migration from older to newer version of Tomcat i faced the same issue.

Comment: @Akshay So what will i do?? What the impact of tomcat version on this.I think earlier it was tomcat 8.0.x and now its 8.2.x

Comment: We solved it by unit testing.Go component by component.Test the database,Datasource,the driver settings,the jars.My problem was that the Jars were not included in the build path.some hibernate jars were not included

Comment: I entirely went through your config file.As far as I know there are no issues.So frankly speaking it is really difficult to point exactly where there is an error.

Comment: @Akshay Does i want to make any relevant changes in pom file if tomcat version changes

Comment: i dont think so.You have got Spring 4.1 and Hibernate  4.2.2 they go well with tomcat 8.2

Comment: Check with the apache dependencies.I think you might want to recheck them as to the compatiblity with Tomcat 8.2

Comment: @Akshay You mean't dependencies like org.apache.httpcomponents,org.apache.tiles,org.apache.commons ??Am i right?

Comment: Yes..just do through it...see if anything is missing.

Comment: @Akshay Did you find anything missing in my pom file?? I was stuck in this because I don't have the latest versions in my local machine and also not able to debug the project in server.

Comment: I am posting the Pom.xml as answer.Looks like you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependencies in your pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is my pom.xml which works with JBoss well.Just make sure you have additional **HIBERNATE** dependencies rest remains the same.